# When I create an iphone window based app, how to tell interface builder create window for retina pixel size?

Tags: iphone

I hope to create an iphone window based app for retina screen?
But I found that the size of window in mainwindow.xib is fixed.
How to adjust it or there is any to tell interface builder create window for retina pixel size?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do anything in terms of the various components you layout in Interface Builder, as it's based around points, not pixels - and as all the iPhone screens sizes are the same in points no action is required.

In terms of any images you're loading, you will need to supply higher resolution (twice the pixel size) versions, but as long as these are named "[original name]@2x.[extension]" they'll simply work automatically.

For more information on the image naming, see the "Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS" section of the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW1) and if you want to delve a little deeper, there's a discussion on "Points Versus Pixels" within the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html).

**UPDATE** - As of the iPhone 5, the iPhone screens are no longer all the same point size. :-)

Comment: Displaying graphics depending on the device model can be done by duplicating image files and adding an ‘@2x’ suffix. So, when the normal image file is named ‘button.png’, the hi-res version should be ‘button@2x.png’. You don’t need any additional code for this.

Comment: @user262325 That's because images are in pixels, not points. (i.e.: They're resolution specific.) As all of the measurements in Interface Builder are in points, they're resolution independent and hence the same on all the iPhones.

Comment: but   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00) {
         // RETINA DISPLAY
    }

Comment: @user262325 You should update your question if you have any other queries.

Comment: check 'RETINA DISPLAY'  is for what?

Comment: @user262325 I've updated my answer. However, there's most likely no need for you to use that check. As I've said, the layouts from Interface Builder will work as-is so all you need to do is supply the updated image files.

Answer (score 1):

The window will be automatically resized for you, you do need concern about the size of your image elements, since retina display uses a bigger size of resolution. You need name your images like this:

```
regular image name: myimage.png
retina image name:  myimage@2x.png
```

When running in an iPhone4 your program will identify the token "@2x" and change the images for that kind of device.

Design your layout using the size of: 640x960 (double of the original: 320x480)

Good luck.