# How to create 1536x2048 framebuffer for iPad Retina sample (GLGravity)

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, retina-display

So of course the first thing I'm trying on my new iPad (4g) is the old [GLGravity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLGravity/Introduction/Intro.html) example. The only modification I've made is to set the target device to "iPad".

However, when running on the device, the UIView's bounds are set to 768,1024 as are the "backingWidth, backingHeight" in createFramebuffer.

Eyeballing the image confirms it's still being rendered at 768x1024. What have I missed - how do I get this to render at native resolution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable conditional support for Retina graphics, as we did for the iPhone 4, you would need to have a line of code like this somewhere in the setup for your OpenGL ES hosting view (GLGravityView, in this case):

```
self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

This makes sure that the content within that view (such as [Quartz drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896968/how-do-i-adjust-a-quartz-2d-context-to-account-for-a-retina-display/3897232#3897232)) is rendered with the 2-pixels-per-point scaling used in the current Retina displays on the iPhone and iPad.

Your view's bounds will remain at the 768 x 1024 point size, but the render buffer will return 1536 x 2048 as its pixel dimensions when queried by `glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES()`. This will allow you to render Retina-level graphics within your OpenGL ES context.

Note that some of Apple's sample code (like GLGravity) [uses the view bounds to size other display elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504614/opengl-es-retina-support/4506090#4506090), so they will appear too small in the scene. You might need to replace calculations based on the view bounds (in points) with the backing width (in pixels) to make sure that the 2.0 scaling of the Retina graphics is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks, I found the other change required in the sample and added a supplemental answer (didn't really fit in comment).

Answer (score 3):

As an expansion on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772612/94239), the GLGravity sample needs another change to ensure the GL viewport is set correctly. This is because the`bounds`property returns Quartz points, not pixels.

```
-(void)setupView
{
  ...
  CGRect rect = self.bounds;
  // new code - modify the viewport dimensions.
  rect.size.width *= self.contentScaleFactor;
  rect.size.height *= self.contentScaleFactor;
  // end of new code
  glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);
  glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: @2x ipad images present, but everything renders @1x on the new iPad. iPhone/iPod Touch works OK on retina and non-retina devices.
Searching the Apple dev forums I found the problem: I am still on Xcode 4.2, building for iOS 5.0. This OS does not foresee the possibility of a retina ipad. So I need to build with 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind of get this.

XIB files [measure in pts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807465/when-i-create-an-iphone-window-based-app-how-to-tell-interface-builder-create-w), not pixels.  A [pt is a unit of distance, like a cm, or a light-year](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference).  A pixel is **not** a unit of distance, it stands for "picture element".  Different devices can have different pixel densities.

Your XIB file tells the size of your display area **in pts**.  iPhone apps default to 320x480 **pts**, iPad 768x1024 **pts**.  You can check this out in your xib file.

Now, `self.contentScaleFactor` that Brad refers to **is the answer**.  What this value does is: ["convert from the default logical coordinate space (768x1024 **pts**) into the device coordinate space of this screen (1536x2048 **px**)."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)

In other words, `self.contentScaleFactor` is a measure of **pixels/pt** used by the device.  This value varies naturally from device to device.  XCode has you specify UI elements in **pts** (unit of real world distance), so things don't appear screwed up on different resolutions.

You can even set `self.contentScaleFactor=4`, which actually looks kinda cool (it supersamples) (but can run slow).

Another gotcha here is *touch events will always be in **pts***, never in pixels.  That is, retina devices still only resolve *touch events* on a 768x1024 scale.

So, if your view supports touch picking, you need to multiply each incoming touch event by `self.contentScaleFactor` in order for the incoming location in **pts** to map to **pixels** in your framebuffer.

Comment: [See also here for "The relationship between drawing coordinates, view coordinates, and hardware coordinates"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)